# QTreeView middle column fill width space instead of last column

Tags: qt, header, size, qtreeview

How can do this:

[image: middle column fill space]

I already tried this way:

```
view->header()->setResizeMode(INDEX_COLUMN_SKU, QHeaderView::Interactive);
view->header()->setResizeMode(INDEX_COLUMN_NAME, QHeaderView::Stretch);
view->header()->setResizeMode(INDEX_COLUMN_QUANTITY, QHeaderView::Interactive);
view->header()->setResizeMode(INDEX_COLUMN_PRICE, QHeaderView::Interactive);
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Did you remember `to view->header()->setStretchLastSection(false)`?

Here are some examples:

### Default Behavior

[image: Default behavior]

### Just disabling stretch on the last column:

```
treeView->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
```

[image: Stretch_Disabled]

### Both attributes combined:

```
treeView->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
treeView->header()->setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

From QT5 onwards:

```
treeView->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
treeView->header()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Stretch); //! qt5 api change
```

[image: Stretch_Disabled+Resizable_Second_Col]

Comment: Yes. I tried, but the last column always takes up too much space

Comment: I would suspect that would only be the case if if you set setStretchLastSection(true), otherwise if it is set false it will shrink down and let INDEX_COLUMN_NAME stretch open. If it still doesn't work, make sure it's false and you could try setting the other columns to QHeaderView::ResizeToContents

Comment: Two quick comments: first, in Qt 5 setResizeMode has been refactored to setSectionResizeMode. Second, setStrechLastSection must be called BEFORE any other call to setSectionResizeMode, if not, it doesn't work correctly.